# How to limit an array list to 10 and display next 10 items on click of more

Tags: android, arraylist, baseadapter

I am adding all the items in `arrayList`, now I want to display only 10 items in my recycler view and click of more 10 more and so on. I want to use same `arrayList`.

Comment: There is not enough to go on. Are you asking how to add items to an ArrayList and clear it?

Comment: how about creating a short `ArrayList` with only 10 items, filled by a `for` loop, which counts till 10. So you just connect that `ArrayList` with your `recyclerview` and if somebody wants to see the next 10 items you refill the short `ArrayList` and show the next ten?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can handle it by yourself in `getCount()` method.
you can put a integer in your adapter class and by each click on more button increase it 1.

```
int num = 1;
```

on more button click:

```
if((adapter.num)*10 < arrayList.size()) 
   adapter.num = adapter.num +1;
```

and in `getCount()` method:

```
 @Override
public int getCount() {
    if(num*10 > arrayList.size()){
        return arrayList.size();
    }else{
       return num*10; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Below is what I did and is working perfectly fine without using any temp array. As already quoted by @MHP `getCount()` will do the trick.

```
   @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if(displaySize > statusList.size())
        return statusList.size();
        else
            return displaySize;
    }
```

Here `displaySize` is number of entries I want to display and statusList is my actual array holding all the entries.

Below is the method that I would call like `adapter.setDisplayCount(10);`

```
 public void setDisplayCount(int numberOfEntries) {
           displaySize = numberOfEntries;
            notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's impossible not depends on arrayList only that's depend on data source like database example :

You would display data from table user ***: user_id , user_name*** , To request the first 10

**SQL statement**

```
Select * from user LIMIT 0,10 ;
```

Next 10

```
Select * from user LIMIT 10,20 ;
```

every time after added the new data in arrayList call **notifyDataSetChanged()** to adapter of your recycler view.

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**Edit :**  or you need to use other **arrayList** and add data ten by ten and every time after add data **notifyDataSetChanged()** to recycler view adapter ;

Answer (score 0):

Better option is to make two array of data, mainArray and backupArray.
First try to add 10 items from backupArray to mainArray. 
onLoadMore-add more 10 items from backupArray to mainArray.
LoadmoreLoginc
Adapter-getView(...)

```
 if(position==10){
   activity.loadMore();
}
```

Comment: Sameer for this approach we have to maintain two array list..better to go with getItemCount() in adapter...btw thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

HERE WE GO

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (arrayList.size()>10){
        return 10;
    }
    return arrayList.size();
}
```